# React Iframe: Accessing localhost with different port numbers results in cross origin security error

Tags: reactjs, security, iframe, cross-domain

I am working on setting iframe and stuck with local testing. I have my app running on localhost:3000

I have setup Iframe in my app with src url set to localhost:1234 for local testing. I was hoping accessing via local host would resolve the cross origin error but looks like since port numbers are different, this doesn't seem to work

SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

I have looked into various stack overflow posts and tried disabling chrome web security, even then this doesn't seem to let me do some local testing.

Any suggestions on how to prevent the cross origin error in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your app (the backend) should send a CORS header (from `localhost:3000` if I understand correctly). A different port (just like a different hostname) counts as a different origin, so the same origin policy applies to requests, and you have to explicitly enable cross-origin requests.

The way to do so is your "backend" must send the response header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:1234
```

if that's where your frontend app is running. For development, you can also send

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Don't do `*` in later stages of your pipeline and especially not in production as you might open your app to further vulnerabilities (CSRF).

If your frontend app uses cookies to authenticate cross-origin, the backend must also send `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`, and your frontend javascript must add `withCredentials: true` to the request. However, it doesn't sound like this is the case for you.

I think this is better than disabling cross-origin restrictions as this would work for any developer without any setup, and without compromising browser security. It gives you full control over which client can access your API, and also allows you to understand cross origin requests better.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do local testing via Safari following the steps here:

Safari -> Preferences -> Advanced

then at the bottom tick Show Develop Menu in menu bar

then in the Develop Menu tick Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing is disabled on some modern browsers by default. [Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) plugin for Chrome adds necessary HTTP headers to perform development on localhost without CORS error.

Comment: This will make your browser insecure, open to potential csrf attacks. As you very rarely do development only in a browser, this is a risk even if you turn it off when not used. Let alone if you don't...

Comment: Yes. This will make the browser insecure.  That's why CORS remains disabled by default. ```Local testing without security error``` means ignoring that security error. Though the method that I have mentioned above works for the desired purpose, it ignores the security error.